# MS Visual Studio cannot create React JS project

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I've got a solution in MS Visual Studio with ASP Net Core Web API project.

I want to add standalone React JS project to this solution.

NPM creates folder with project in `\AppData\Local\Temp\` folder but cannot copy it to the folder where my solution is with error:

`Couldn't find a part of the path.`

If I run `npm start` in temp folder, it starts fine server and shows default page.

How can it be solved?

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.0

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @kylie No I haven't found solution and created project manually, by copy/pasting